Optimisation fails / not evaluating when a if statement is included in the problem
Have an optimisation problem which I recently added an IF statement.
Optimisation fails (or partially evaluated in my longer code) when the section in (**) is included.
Can someone please explain why - all I am trying to do is to include a balance if certain condition is met (in this case, include balance in optimisation if negative). Also would note that said balance depends on the optimisation problem too.
I suspect it may be the IF statement ultimately flowing into the constraint?
Code below is a simplified version of my longer code.
ent1U = {10, 10, 10};
ent2U = {30, 20, 20};
totalentU = ent1U + ent2U;

ent1S = {+s1, +s1, +s1};
ent2S = {+s2, +s2, +s2};
totalentS = ent1S + ent2S;

open2T = Total[-totalentU - totalentS];
open1 = Total[-ent1U - ent1S];
open2 = Total[-ent2U - ent2S];

woT = {open2T, open2T + totalentU[[1]] + totalentS[[1]], 
   open2T + totalentU[[1]] + totalentS[[1]] + totalentU[[2]] + 
    totalentS[[2]], 
   open2T + totalentU[[1]] + totalentS[[1]] + totalentU[[2]] + 
    totalentS[[2]] + totalentU[[3]] + totalentS[[3]]};
wo1 = {open1, open1 + ent1U[[1]] + ent1S[[1]], 
   open1 + ent1U[[1]] + ent1S[[1]] + ent1U[[2]] + ent1S[[2]], 
   open1 + ent1U[[1]] + ent1S[[1]] + ent1U[[2]] + ent1S[[2]] + 
    ent1U[[3]] + ent1S[[3]]};
wo2 = {open2, open2 + ent2U[[1]] + ent2S[[1]], 
   open2 + ent2U[[1]] + ent2S[[1]] + ent2U[[2]] + ent2S[[2]], 
   open2 + ent2U[[1]] + ent2S[[1]] + ent2U[[2]] + ent2S[[2]] + 
    ent2U[[3]] + 
    ent2S[[3]]}(* this is the part causing issue \
+{If[wo1[[1]]<0,wo[[1]],0],0,0,0}*);

c1 = 30;
c2 = 25;

cost = -3*s1*c1 - 3*s2*c2;
vari = {s1, s2};
constr = {woT[[1]] >= 0, woT[[2]] >= 0, woT[[3]] >= 0, wo2[[1]] >= 40,
    s1 <= 0, s2 <= 0};

sol = NMinimize[{cost, constr}, vari]

woT /. sol[[2]]
wo1 /. sol[[2]]
wo2 /. sol[[2]]


The variables in NMinimize will be localized. Because of this, you need an "Evaluate" in {If[wo1[[1]] < 0, Evaluate@wo1[[1]], 0], 0, 0, 0} (If has the Attribute HoldRest).

Thanks @DanielHuber, I tried including Evaluate but it didnt seem to work. Looking into this simplified problem now (rather than my full code), I noticed I have created a conditional constraint problem, which turned my problem into a non-linear one?

Is wo supposed to be wo1? Also, can you explain what the failure is?

Is this a question about programming or a question about the math?

Hi, its both. if mathematically a feasible problem then how do i solve programming. if not, appreciate any pointer on the math problem
